# Problems with hot encoding

Tags: python, object, linear-regression, one-hot-encoding

I am conducting a bit of research on video game sales and would like to run a linear regression test. My independent variables are all non-numeric (Publisher, Platform and Genre). I tried using LabelEncoder but it didn't work out for me. My resulting R2 score is almost zero. Any solutions?

This the code I used for the Encoding:

```
vg = video_games.copy()

vg.head()

LE = LabelEncoder()
feature = ["Platform", "Genre", "Publisher"]


for col in feature:
    vg[col] = LE.fit_transform(video_games[col])

print(vg.shape)
data = pd.get_dummies(data=vg, columns=['Platform', 'Genre', 'Publisher'])
print(data.shape) 


IndepVar_train, IndepVar_test, DepVar_train, DepVar_test = train_test_split(IndepVar, DepVar,         test_size=.2, random_state=42)
IndepVar_train.shape, DepVar_train.shape, IndepVar_test.shape, DepVar_test.shape

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(IndepVar_train, DepVar_train)
pred = lr.predict(IndepVar_test)
r2_Result = r2_score(DepVar_test,pred)

print(r2_Result)
print(lr.score(IndepVar_test, DepVar_test))
```

```
0.001819941354928023
0.001819941354928023
```

Comment: Which score did you expect to get instead?

Comment: What's your dependent variable? Is there a reason to think it's correlated with your independent variables?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I was expecting a score close to at least 50 percent since others that have conducted a similar kind of research has obtained around that. My dependent variable is Global Sales.

Comment: I would like to think Genre, for instance, might have an impact on Global Sales. Action games are the most popular genre so it would be safe to assume that games in the Action genre would sell high globally. Just trying to find if there is a viable relationship of these factors, if any, with Global Sales.